# Grouping by last row where a value occurred & aggregating rows before that las occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, grouping

I have a situation.

I have a dataset where  different distinct 'IDs' have different actions in certain periods
The thing is that an unique 'ID', can appear multiple time, but only sometime they perform a certain action.

For example:

| ID | Day | is_Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 0 |
| x | 2 | 0 |
| x | 3 | 1 |
| y | 2 | 1 |
| y | 3 | 2 |
| z | 1 | 0 |
| z | 2 | 1 |

What I want to achieve is an aggregattion of the information that happened before the LAST is_Action that occured.

For example, out of above table I want to achieve:

| ID | days_passed_till_action | actions_did_till_last_action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2 | 0 |
| y | 1 | 1 |
| z | 1 | 0 |

Please let me know if would be possible to achieve something like that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try these, assume the dataframe is sorted by `Day` and `is_Action`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'days_passed_till_action': df.groupby('ID')['Day'].count()-1, 
'actions_did_till_last_action': df.groupby('ID')['is_Action'].first()}).reset_index()
```